# Brand new bike with a stuck chain link

Tags: chain

I bought a brand new Fuji Nevada and I've had a horrible experience.

I noticed skipping while pedaling and found a stuck chain link. No matter how much or hard I wiggle it, it won't loosen up.

Any advice before taking it back to the shop? Frankly I want to return the bike. I'm so annoyed! It cost me a lot of money too.

Comment: Take some pliers and a rag and gently straighten it out.  Torque it side to side to loosen it up.

Comment: Rather than wiggle it in the direction it "wants" to flex, attempt to "bend" it in the direction in which it is not supposed to flex.

Comment: Im not wiggeling it the way its supposed to bend, im wiggeling it where it dosent bend, if that makes any sense. Annd ive used a plier aswell. Its completly stuck. If i bend it in a position it will stay that way.

Comment: If the bike is new, take it back and request they fix it.  Freeing up the chain is fine, or you could request a new chain to be fitted at some discount.

Comment: What we're saying is to flex it sideways, fairly forcefully.  (But of course you really should just take it back to the shop where you bought it.)

Answer (score 2):

I agree if the bike is new and has not been abused the  shop repair it for free. I have repaired several "new" bikes with a sticking link. I generally remove the affected link and replace it with a master link for a chain of the correct size. Total cost under $5 if you already have a chain tool. I don't know why it happens, perhaps just a manufacturing defect.

Comment: Ok, but does pedaling with a stuck link damage the gears? Its XT so i dont want to ruin it even if the chain is fixed.

Comment: what i meant by the above comment, some time i pedal and if I stand while cycling and the stuck chain is in the rear gears u get this huge click sound and emtpy pedal move. Its hard to describe but i think you know what i mean.

ofc ive stopped even using the bike now until i get the link fixed.

Comment: I would avoid riding it in the position that causes the skip/jump/click.

Comment: well every position is skipping. Every time the link is going trough the rear derailleur it skips. I can see that it cant fit the gears so it moves the derailleur slightly forward. I really hope my derailleur is not broken.

How can i check for other errors? Im not spending a single money on fixing it srs.

Answer (score 0):

I work at a shop that sells Fuji and I've built many Nevadas. I'll admit that certain models are great and the lower ones are, well.....not as great. However, I assure you that problem is not specific to that brand/model; it's a component issue. I have seen that problem before, and I just pushed the pin out and replaced it with a Shimano chain pin (relative to the speed of the chain, of course: 6,7,8Spd or 9spd  or 10spd or 11spd). A 3 pack of pins for future us should cost $5-$10 depending where you get it.  Or Master Links work as well.